# React Native Change styling by state

Tags: react-native, native, styling

It does not work, when this.state.item1 is true.

```
 onfocus: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    width: 800,
  },
 this.state = {     
      item1: true,   
  }; 
      <Image key={"item1"} style={this.state.item1 && styles.onfocus} source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/c-bata/react-native-focus-scroll/blob/master/example/assets/rokko-yamatanoorochi-ipa.jpg?raw=true' }} />
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're referencing `item1` as the key, if you're trying to use the state item you need to use `this.state.item1`.

```
<Image key={"this.state.item1"} style={this.state.item1 && styles.onfocus} source={{ uri: 
'https://github.com/c-bata/react-native-focus- 
scroll/blob/master/example/assets/rokko-yamatanoorochi-ipa.jpg?raw=true' }} />
```

However, the key shouldn't be a boolean value, it needs to be a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it should be work

```
<Image key={"item1"} style={this.state.item1 === 'your_condition' ? styles.onfocus : style.another_styles} source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/c-bata/react-native-focus-scroll/blob/master/example/assets/rokko-yamatanoorochi-ipa.jpg?raw=true' }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operators to show styles on conditions:

" (condition)? satisfied_condition : unsatisfied_condition "

```
<Image key={"item1"} style={(this.state.item1==true) ? styles1 : style2} source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/c-bata/react-native-focus-scroll/blob/master/example/assets/rokko-yamatanoorochi-ipa.jpg?raw=true' }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
<Image key={"item1"} 
    style={this.state.item1 ? styles.onfocus : {}} 
    source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/c-bata/react-native-focus-scroll/blob/master/example/assets/rokko-yamatanoorochi-ipa.jpg?raw=true' }} 
/>
```